# Access system:string resource dictionary XAML in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, localization, resourcedictionary, locbaml

How do I access the contents in a resource dictionary using C#?

For example, here is my code in XAML:

```
<system:String x:Key="NewGroup">New Group Name</system:String>
```

And I want to access it here in C#:

```
    private void OnAddGroup(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        BooksGroupInfo group = new BooksGroupInfo();
        group.GroupName = "New Group" + TheTabControl.Items.Count;
        TabItem tab = AddGroup(group);
        _currentLibrary.addGroup(group);
        _currentLibrary.CurrentGroup = group;

    }
```

Instead of typing "New Group" in C#, I would like to replace that and have access in the resource dictionary in XAML. So the command will automatically get the Name that is in the resource dictionary.

I've tried a couple of solutions like:

```
(System.String)this.FindResource("NewGroup"); 
Application.Current.Resources[typeof(System.String)];
```

and so on...
but they do not seem to work.

I am doing a Localization using locbaml and it doesn't parse the Text/Name on C# (or I don't know how to) and that was the only solution I thought was possible.

Answer (score 5):

Usually using [FrameworkElement.FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx) like this:  `string s = this.FindResource("NewGroup") as string;` works. It is more likely that the resource with the key "NewGroup" does not exist in the scope of your control or window (whatever `this` is). You must make sure that the resource is there. E.g. if your resource comes from another file you have to use [MergedDictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.mergeddictionaries.aspx). You can test if the resource is actually acessible try to acess it from XAML that belongs to your codebehind where `OnAddGroup` is definde.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: hello.. thank you for the reply but i still cant get it to work. Sorry kinda new at this..

Comment: I added this on the code and it is not accepting the 4th line.. i dont know if i did it correctly, just added the source of the resource dictionary..

Comment: ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary = sender as ResourceDictionary;
            resourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("Source.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

            BooksGroupInfo group = new BooksGroupInfo();
            group.GroupName =  (string resourceDictionary = this.FindResource("NewGroup") as string) + TheTabControl.Items.Count;
            TabItem tab = AddGroup(group);
            _currentLibrary.addGroup(group);
            _currentLibrary.CurrentGroup = group;

Comment: group.GroupName = (this.FindResource("NewGroup") as string) + TheTabControl.Items.Count;

Comment: I don't think you need this: ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary = sender as ResourceDictionary; resourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("Source.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

Comment: The resource dictionary must be added to the resource section of your main XAML using mergeddictionaries

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot guarantee the existence of your resources then using

[FrameworkElement.TryFindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tryfindresource.aspx)

will be a better solution. It is similar to `FindResource` but rather than throwing an exception, `TryFindResource` returns `null` if no resource with the provided key is found. (Implementation of `TryXxx()` methods is called *TryGet Pattern*.) Sample in XAML code-behind:

```
button.Content = this.TryFindResource("NewGroup");
```